# AngularJS register events from legacy library

Tags: angularjs

I have a javascript library that is not written for AngularJS, it has some events that are raised in different times, how can i track theese events from an AngularJS controller to manage the state (model, view etc)?

Comment: How does using AngularJS affect that? Just do it like you normally would.

Comment: how can i tell angularjs that an event in a library occured without modifing that library and passing to it my scope?

Comment: I suggest you do some research on why we use `$scope.$apply()` for situations like this. As stated above, you listen for the events like you normally would. When the event occurs, you use `$scope.$apply()` to tell Angular that something outside of the Angular framework has changed. Finally, if you're still stuck, show us the actual code you're using.

Comment: The AngularJS event system uses scope methods: [$on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on), [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit), and `$broadcast` and is documented in [AngularJS rootScope.scope API Reference -- $on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this way:

```
function MyController($scope, $window){

    $window.thridpartyLibrary.on('somethingHappend', function(evt){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.myVariable = evt;
        });
    });
}
```

E.g.: with `$scope.$apply` you can let your angular context be aware of the event that is triggered from another library.